# Требуется отключить стандартный размер буферизации в 4096 байт

Tags: android

Уже много времени боюсь над тем, чтобы отключить буферихацию стандартную размером в 4096 байт InputStream, которая установлена в линукс подобных системах.
Есть команда stdbuf, но в андроиде такой команды для терминала нет, нужно отдельно как-то ее подключать.

Мне нужно именно обрабатывать в реальном времени, в не пока в процессе накопился 4096 byte. Нужно работать, если в строке уже есть 18 байт.
Если точнее это команда getevent event0, которая нам выводит данные о нажатии на экран. В любом терминале с рут доступом данные выводятся для этой команды сразу.

Я встретил на англоязычной ветке такой пост 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296374/resolved-android-interactive-shell-runtime-getruntime-exec
Но до конца разобраться не могу что к чему...
Разобрался до момента Important, но дальше что-то не понимаю, что к чему...
До автора поста не могу достучаться...

```
public class TouchEventThread2 extends Thread {

    DataOutputStream dos1, dos2;
    Process process1, process2;
    String cmd = "getevent /dev/input/event0";

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        process(process1, dos1);
        process(process2, dos2);

        boolean firstProcess = true;
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (true) {
                if (firstProcess) {
                    cmd("getevent /dev/input/event0", dos2);
                    cmd("quit", dos1);
                } else {
                    cmd("getevent /dev/input/event0", dos1);
                    cmd("quit", dos2);
                }
                firstProcess = !firstProcess;
            }
        }
    }

    public void process (Process process, DataOutputStream dos) {
        try {
            process = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"su", "-c", "sh"}).start();
            dos = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void cmd (String cmd, DataOutputStream dos) {
        try {
            dos.writeBytes(cmd + "\n");
            dos.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: показывай свой код

Comment: @Пионерка
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xbgpncq5WjMfJJ8XtS6JkD1Makej2uX8cAPlFxfh9QU/edit?usp=sharing
Всё, что понял...

Comment: Есть у кого-то мысли по решению проблемы?

Comment: Ребята, нужны мысли для решения вопроса. @Пионерка

Comment: До @VasileM достучаться не получается